# Mac mini 1.66 no audio in device manager

Tags: windows-7, windows, mac, drivers, mac-mini

Windows 7 installed perfectly except that there is no sound. Not only that, but there is no audio device in the Device Manager screen. I've tried the realtek drivers etc. with no success.

Does anyone know what the chipset is, or how to confirm it? And a solution would be even better!!

Comment: Are you running this on an Emulator? Or are you saying you actually installed this on the Mac Mini directly and removed the Mac OS?

Comment: I was running with bootcamp, but now I'm just trying to run Windows 7 since that version of the Mac Mini is no longer supported.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the final solution from where you are would be to:

1: Uninstall the RealTek drivers (under delete program)

2: Delete audio components (from the device manager)

3: Restart

4: Locate the RealTek driver on your or Mac Install CD (or from a download from RealTek's site) (BOOTCAMP > Drivers > RealTekSetup)

5: Right-click on the installer and select "troubleshoot compatibility"

6: Wait for it to finish "detecting issues"

7: Select "this program worked on an earlier version of Windows, but won't install or display correctly now"

8: Select Windows Vista or Windows XP

9: Wait for it to finish "resolving issues", the installer will start

Hopefully this will have you up and running.